# Grant-AzDiskAccess in c#

Tags: c#, azure

I'm writing a utility to move vms between 2 azure tenants.
I'm developping it in C# as part of a larger project.
Microsoft provides instructions in powershell:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/disks-upload-vhd-to-managed-disk-powershell

It seams pretty straightforward but I can't find how to get the SAS urls of the source and destination in c#.

```
$sourceDiskSas = Grant-AzDiskAccess -ResourceGroupName $sourceRG -DiskName $sourceDiskName -DurationInSecond 86400 -Access 'Read'

$targetDiskSas = Grant-AzDiskAccess -ResourceGroupName $targetRG -DiskName $targetDiskName -DurationInSecond 86400 -Access 'Write'
```

What rest apis or nuget packages and classes should I use to achieve the same in c#?
I searched for quite a long time and didn't find a documented solution on the web?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Disk Grant Access REST API

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/disks/grant-access?tabs=HTTP

Comment: thanks, good catch. Is there an existing sdk, ,c# library or nuget package that already encapsulate this?

Answer (score 0):

The below is the NuGet used for Azure SDK for .NET.

```
Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute
```

[image]

Using C# code

```
using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        ps.AddCommand("Connect-AzAccount");
        ps.AddParameter("SubscriptionId", subId);
        ps.Invoke();
        ps.Commands.Clear();
        ps.AddCommand("Grant-AzDiskAccess");
        ps.AddParameter("ResourceGroupName", rgName);
        ps.AddParameter("DiskName", disk);
        ps.AddParameter("VMName", vm);
        ps.AddParameter("Access", "ReadWrite");
        ps.AddParameter("DurationInSeconds", 3600);
        
        ps.Invoke();
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your C# code uses the PS modules, and not the nuget package you showed earlier. You could get a great answer if your example actually showed how to use the management library.